Create a script that loops deleting a number of rows in a table
I've tried to create a script that loops deleting a random number of rows from a table per campaign. It works for the first campaign but doesn't for the others
Below is my script. I declare the attendees deleted variable then I use the rand() function to generate a random number which I then use in my delete statement via using a CTE and setting a row number. It works for the first campaign but then doesn't for the rest even though when I look at the print statement, it shows the random number generated.
DECLARE @CampaignID INT
SET @CampaignID = 1

WHILE @CampaignID <= 1000
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AttendeesDeleted INT

        SELECT @AttendeesDeleted = ROUND(RAND() * 10000, 0)

        ;WITH attendees AS (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY  CampaignAttendeeID) AS rn
            FROM Warehouse.CampaignAttendees
        )
        DELETE
        FROM attendees 
        WHERE rn > @AttendeesDeleted
        AND CampaignID = @CampaignID

        PRINT 'Attendees Deleted: ' + CAST(@AttendeesDeleted AS VARCHAR)
            
        SET @CampaignID = @campaignID + 1
    END

Do I need to maybe create the random select script as a function then run it as a function?


You need to provide explanation of what "doesn't work" means. Example data would help a lot.

I've added a screenshot of when I run this script for the first 2 campaigns. It deletes the correct number for the first campaign but then deletes all the rows for the second campaign even though in the print script it shows the amount it should be deleting

Thanks Peter. That has done the trick

The WHERE CampaignID = @CampaignID part belongs at the SELECT statement, not at the DELETE.
This change causes the ROW_NUMBER() to be calculated for the rows belonging to a campaign, instead of for all rows in the table.
